# How can I show a SQLITE error message created in a SQL trigger into Python Flask code?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I want to be able to get this message to show on my Flask app using Python code. The goal is to show on the client side that the Patient ID is already registered or is a duplicated entry.

Here is the SQL code of what I did here.

```
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_duplicate_Patient_IDs 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON pt_register WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pt_register WHERE 
Patient_ID=new.Patient_ID)
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        RAISE(ABORT, "Duplicate entry. Patient ID already registered/submitted! "); 
END;
```

What I am missing is how to show this message when I enter in the same Patient ID more than once to show as a Flask flash error message instead of a SQL Integrity Error Page. Any tips or advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_duplicate_Patient_IDs 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON pt_register WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pt_register WHERE 
Patient_ID=new.Patient_ID)
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        RAISE(ABORT, "Duplicate entry. Patient ID already registered/submitted! "); 
END;
```

Here is my Python code here:

```
class pt_register(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Patient_ID=db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    no_health_services=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class Pt_RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    PT_ID=StringField(validators=[DataRequired(message="Patient ID must be six characters long (numbers ONLY)!"), Length(min=6, max=6, message="Patient ID must be six characters long (numbers ONLY)!")])
    no_health_services=BooleanField()
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

registered = []

def validate_Patient_ID(self, Patient_ID): 
    if Patient_ID is registered: 
        flash("Patient registered successfully")
        return redirect(url_for("pt_registration"))
    else: 
        raise ValidationError("Duplicate entry. Patient ID already registered/submitted! ")   

    # def validate_Patient_ID(self, Patient_ID): 
    #     existing_Patient_ID = Patient_ID.query.filter_by(Patient_ID=Patient_ID.data).first()
    #     if existing_Patient_ID: 
    #         raise ValidationError("Patient_ID already exists. Please scan for a different Patient ID.")
```

Here is the Jinja2 template code here:

```
{% if form.submit %}

{% for error_message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %} 

    {{% error_message %}}
 
{% endfor %}


{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for this? Declare `Patiend_ID` as a unique column in the table definition and the exception will be raised automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Right. I just did this but I would like to show this as a notification on the front end of my Flask app to my users.

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch errors from a query. It should catch an error created by `RAISE()` just like any built-in SQL error.